# inners join con 3 tablas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo 3 tablas con esta estructura

Marcas - tabla

- id
- name
- description

sucursals

- id
- marca_id
- name

Questionary

- id
- sucursal_id
- name
- value

En algún punto entro a la vista **show** de las marcas
en el tengo que realizar ciertas operaciones de sacar un promedio, pero tengo que acceder al value de la tabla **Questionary**, entonces mi pregunta es, como puedo hacer una consulta que solo me muestre el value de dicha tabla pero solo los que pertenezcan a una sucursal, lo he intentado de varias maneras y esta fue la ultima que probe

```
$count = DB::table('questionnaires as q')
                        ->join('sucursals as s', function($on){
                            $on->on('q.sucursal_id', '=', 's.id');
                        })
                        ->get();
            ddd($count);
```

entonces el output es que me muestra todo lo de la tabla, y solo me deberia mostrar los datos que tienen que ver con sucursal_id

Answer (score 0):

Partimos de que sería ideal tengas un modelo por cada tabla de tu ejercicio y sus respectivas relaciones en cada uno, identificando que son relaciones de: **`1:N`**

**Modelos**

Modelo Marca.php

```
class Marca extends Model 
{
    public function sucursales()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Sucursal::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo Sucursal.php

```
class Sucursal extends Model 
{
    public function marca()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Marca::class);
    }

    public function questionaries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Questionary::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo Questionary.php

```
class Questionary extends Model 
{
    public function sucursal()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Sucursal::class);
    }
}
```

En la consulta cargamos al modelo Questionary con su sucursal asociada, seleccionando la columna `value` y filtramos por medio de un `where`

```
$algunId = 10;
$data = Questionary::select('value')
                    ->with('sucursal')
                    ->where('sucursal_id', $algunId)
                    ->get();
```

Comment: Ese es el asunto, ese $id que mencionas solo le puedo pasar el id de la marca

Comment: como lo explique estoy en la vista show del controlador de marcas, entonces acceso al id de sucursal no tengo, solo al id marca

Comment: Disculpa pero sigo sin notar el problema pues con esta consulta obtienes la columna de Cuestionarios relacionándolo con Sucursal y filtrando por el sucursal_id lo de menos es hacerla desde el controller e invocar el o los modelos necesarios

Answer (score 0):

Me costó mucho entender tu pregunta, ya que en tu ejemplo no utilizas en ninguna parte la tabla 'marcas', pero deduje que en tu método show recibes el id de la marca con el que deseas hacer el join, entonces, dijiste que solo puedes pasarle el id de la marca, ahora, puedes almacenar ese id de la marca del que hablaste a una variable $marca_id y quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$data = Marca::leftJoin('sucursals', 'marcas.id', 'sucursals.marca_id')
               ->leftJoin('questionnaires', 'sucursals.id', 'questionnaires.sucursal_id')
               ->select('questionnaires.value')
               ->where('id', $marca_id)
               ->get();
```

Comment: Por qué left join?

Comment: Si no existe ninguna coincidencia para alguna de las filas de la tabla de la izquierda, de igual forma todos los resultados de la primera tabla se muestran.
No es necesario que utilizes leftJoin, también puedes utilizar join.